# Speed problem with SPOJ occurence counting in perl

Tags: perl, optimization

I'm having a problem with a task similar to this one:
[*click (translated)*](http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpl.spoj.pl%2Fproblems%2FKC004) (the one I was assigned with has way bigger tests and a lower time limit). A quick translation of the task:

Write a program that checks how many times the given number occurred in a given sequence.

Input: Given number, how many numbers are in the sequence, the sequence of numbers

Output: The number of occurrences

My solutions so far:

**1:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<>) {
    $in = $_;
    @nums = split / /, $in, 3;

    $what = shift @nums;
    shift @nums;
    $rest = shift @nums;
    $rest = " ".$rest." ";

    $sum = () = $rest =~ /(?<=\s)$what(?=\s)/g;

    print $sum;
    print "\n";
}
```

**2:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<>) {
    $in = $_;
    @nums = split / /, $in, 3;

    $what = shift @nums;
    shift @nums;
    $rest = shift @nums;
    $rest = " ".$rest." ";

    if(!$reg{$what}){
        $reg{$what} = qr/(?<=\s)$what(?=\s)/;
    }
    $sum = () = $rest =~ /$reg{$what}/g;

    print $sum;
    print "\n";
}
```

I also tried the brute force approach, hash tables, grep... All exceed the given time limit, and I've got no idea how to write anything that will work faster than the above two. Any ideas?

**edit**: After getting rid of copying lists (turns out the numbers can also be negative):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while ($line = <>) {
        $line =~ s/^(-?\d+) \d+//;
        $what = $1;

        $sum = () = $line =~ / $what\b/g;

    print $sum;
    print "\n";
}
```

**edit2**: via http://www.chengfu.net/2005/10/count-occurrences-perl/:

```
print $sum = (($line =~ s/ $1\b//g)+0);
```

resulted in 2x faster code than:

```
print $sum = () = $line =~ / $1\b/g;
```

Works now, thanks :)

Comment: how large are the datasets and what is the time limit? :)

Comment: The spoj test is secret, but I got an example test with 1k lines and ~600 numbers per line. The time limit is 1s. I've no way to check how long the above two run on spoj :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you're doing an awful lot of copying.  I've marked each time you copy a large string in your first example:

```
while (<>) {
    $in = $_;                   # COPY
    @nums = split / /, $in, 3;  # COPY

    $what = shift @nums;
    shift @nums;
    $rest = shift @nums;        # COPY
    $rest = " ".$rest." ";      # COPY

    $sum = () = $rest =~ /(?<=\s)$what(?=\s)/g;

    print $sum;
    print "\n";
}
```

To speed things up, avoid the copies.  For example, use `while ($in = <>)` (or just skip `$in` and use `$_`).

For extracting `$what` and the count, I think I'd try this instead of `split`:

```
$in =~ s/^(\d+) \d+//;
$what = $1;
```

Instead of adding a space fore and aft, just use `\b` instead of lookarounds with `\s`.

```
    $sum = () = $in =~ /\b$what\b/g;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it's still too slow ;(